# Calling Javascript function from ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "tmpdata.xml",
         dataType: "xml"
    }).done(function(xml){   
 // alert("Hello Yagya");
        file  = $(xml).find("segment[id="+metric+"][name="+segment+"]").text();
        alert("Calling tmp file function");
        tmp(file);
   });
```

//Consider metric and segment names are alraedy assigned

In above code I am trying to call javascript function after fetching filename from xml file, But It seems that due to asynchronous call, tmp function is not called and also unable to access file name outside ajax function, please help me to come out of this problem.

Comment: "due to asynchronous call, tmp function is not called", that can't be true. Do you see any error on the console?

Comment: Can you expand the example to show us where you are declaring file, metric and segment etc! and what `tmp()` is supposed to do.

Comment: @iLikePrograms, metric and segments are declared inside function enclosing ajax call, tmp is a different function written in javascript only.

Comment: declare global variable to reach the outside as well

Comment: Debugging error "string is not a function" on  tmp(file)

Comment: @sakir, I did I declared file as global varaible but it's not giving desired results

Comment: it gave what result  ?

Comment: Same problem, unable to access file name outside ajax call

Comment: asynchronous call, cause to problem I guess

Comment: @yagyavrat From how it sounds, check to see if you have somehow overwritten `tmp` with a `string`. It sounds like that has happened and it is trying to use `tmp` as a `function`, when its somehow a `string`

Comment: pls give me info if it works or not

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "tmpdata.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success:function(xml){   
    // alert("Hello Yagya");
    file  = $(xml).find("segment[id="+metric+"][name="+segment+"]").text();
    alert("Calling tmp file function");
    tmp(file);
   }
});
```